# Can logging into institute's student portal be considered as student ID

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, india

I am going to be flying back to my hometown during my holidays, but the issue is that my Aadhaar card is not updated, i.e., it is not linked with any phone number. In this scenario, I was suggested to use my student ID, but we are not provided with any ID cards from my institute. So, my real question is, can I prove that I am a student by logging into my institute's student portal with my roll number (in the portal, there is a picture of mine) in airport?

Comment: Highly unlikely. What country, what route and what airport ? Most countries do publish a list of acceptable IDs.

Comment: Aadhaar is for India, you can assume domestic flying in India

Answer (score 4):

No, you need an original Student ID card

From [Air India](https://www.airindia.in/new-documents-to-carry.htm) (emphasis mine) :

> Domestic Travel
>
> Passengers must be in possession of a Valid Ticket issued in his / her
> name along with any of the following Valid Photo Identity Documents in
> **original*** for entry into the Airport and travel.
>
> - Passport,
> - Voter Photo Identity card issued by Election Commission of India,
> - Aadhaar or m-Aadhaar issued by Unique Identification Authority of India (UIDAI),
> - PAN Card issued by Income Tax Department,
> - Driving License issued by RTO,
> - Service Photo Identity Card issued by Central / State Government, Public Sector Undertakings, local bodies or Public Limited Companies,
> - Student Photo Identity Cards issued by Government Institutions/ Government recognized Educational Institutions,
> - Nationalized Bank Passbook with attested Photograph,
> - Pension card / Pension documents having photograph of the passenger,
> - Disability Photo ID Card / handicapped medical certificate issued by the respective State / UT Governments / Administrations.
>
> No identity proof is required in respect of Infant/Minor, when
> accompanied by their parents / guardian who is a traveling and having
> a valid identity proof as listed above. However, an unaccompanied
> minor must carry a valid identity proof as listed above.
>
> For a passenger who for some valid reasons is not in a position to
> produce any of the above listed photo identity proofs, the Identity
> Certificate issued by a Group 'A' Gazetted Officer of the Central /
> State Government on his / her official letterhead with passenger's
> photograph duly attested, will be valid for this purpose.

Now, even if it isn't upgraded, you likely can travel with your Aadhaar, but if you have one of the above proofs, make sure have it on you